# Native library does not load in ICS

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to load a native library (related to opencv), and with every phone I've tested it on, it works flawlessly. I have since tested on ICS (nexus 4), and the library has an issue loading. I get the following error message:

```
12-29 10:33:31.279: I/cameraController(11868): OpenCV loaded successfully
12-29 10:33:31.279: D/dalvikvm(11868): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.skinanalytics.skinuploader-1/libnative_sample.so 0x4223e240
12-29 10:33:31.279: D/dalvikvm(11868): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.skinanalytics.skinuploader-1/libnative_sample.so 0x4223e240
12-29 10:33:31.279: D/dalvikvm(11868): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.skinanalytics.skinuploader-1/libnative_sample.so 0x4223e240, skipping init
```

So the main OpenCV lib loads fine, but the library I'm using doesn't. Are there any differences on ICS that I'm not noticing?

Comment: There are no any real issues in the attached log fragment.

Comment: To make @AndreyKamaev 's remark more specific: "No JNI_OnLoad found" is just a (common) hint/warning, not an actual issue. Any more info in the log?

Comment: Unless of course your library *does* contain a JNI_Onload section :)

Comment: Just to make sure: You *didn't* modify your target SDK, you just tested your (existing) application on ICS for the first time. Correct?

Comment: The major change introduced in ICS is they changed the way JNI references work. If you were somehow cheating a little with these before, your stuff will now break under ICS (see http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html). I'd definitely expect some info in LogCat though.

Comment: Thanks for this. It hasn't solved the problem but is interesting!